# Is sealant recommended/required over receptacle or other ceiling fixtures located in attic?

Tags: electrical, attic

I noticed my attic has a few recess lights just sitting in attic insulation and I was planning on adding a new receptacle via my attic ceiling. Do you recommend adding some sealant around the electric fixture or is it required by code in any US states? If it is recommended/required, could I use a Duct Seal Compound (putty) such as this one: [RectorSeal Duct Seal Compound](https://www.rectorseal.com/rectorseal-duct-seal-compound/)

I'm thinking such sealant would go where the wires enter the electric fixture. A putty like this could at least be removed where some foam products I've seen look more permanent.

Comment: Not required, but there is a lot more of this going on these days with a focus on efficient building practices.  Sealing outlet covers and light fixture boxes is important when you're trying to be ultra-efficient, but you might not see much gain from it in older construction.

Comment: I was more concerned about a fire hazard than efficiencies. It didn't seem like much of a hazard to me, but just wanted to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sealant is required but the cutout for the box needs to be tight (not a large oversized hole) the cover plate makes the seal. The lights usually have a trim ring that seals any small gaps between the fixture.